# Checkbox show/hide not working with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to show an email field only if a checkbox is checked.

If the checkbox is not checked the email field must be hidden.

Here is my code:

```
$('#chkbx').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.is(':checked')) {
        $('.email').hide();
        $('.email').remove();
    } else {
        $('.email').show();
    }
});
```

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8">
        <label class="checkbox-inline col-xs-10">
            <input type="checkbox" ID="chkbx"> Email me the report when ready.
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group email">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8">
        <div class="col-xs-8">
            <input type="text" class="form-control "  placeholder="Enter your email">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using the [`toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function, which is designed to handle this type of behavior?

```
$('#chkbx').click(function () {
       // This will show / hide your element accordingly
       $('.email').toggle();
});
```

You can also pass in a given condition to the function to determine if it should be shown or not :

```
// Show or hide depending on the state of your current checkbox element
$('.email').toggle(this.checked);
```

Additionally, you don't likely want to call the [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) function, as that will entirely remove it from the DOM, rendering it unable to be accessed in the future.

Comment: I put the remove so  no data is passed when empty or disabled and hidden.. when it unchecked

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('#chkbx').change(function () {

   $('.email').toggle();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to change the HTML a little bit, you could easily do it with CSS-only.

You can use the `~` operator to select the next `input` that comes after the `input[type=checkbox]:checked`:

```css
.form-group input.form-control {
  display: none;
}

.form-group input[type=checkbox]:checked ~ input.form-control {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-8">
        <input type="checkbox" ID="chkbx">
        <label for="chkbx" class="checkbox-inline col-xs-10">Email me the report when ready.</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your email">
    </div>
</div>
```